# Functional scala log accumulator

Tags: scala, logging, scala-cats

I'm working on a Scala project using cats library, mainly. In there, we have calls like

```
for {
   _ <- initSomeServiceAndLog("something from a far away service")
   _ <- initSomeOtherServiceAndLog("something from another far away service")
   a <- b()
   c <- d(a)
  } yield c
```

Imagine that b also logs something or might throw a business error (I know, we avoid to throw in Scala, but it's not the case right now). I'm looking for a solution to accumulate logs and print them all in the end, in a single message. 
For a happy path, I saw that Writer Monad from Cats might be an acceptable solution.
But what if b method throws? The requirements are to logs everything - all previous logs and the error message, in a single message, with some kind of unique trace ID.
Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is harder than it sounds. `Writer[L, A]` is basically a wrapper allowing composition of functions: `A => (L, A2)` such that `L` would be passed around and sometimes appended to. `WriterT[F, L, A]` would allow `A => F[(L A2)]` - that means that if value in `F` turns to failure (because it is e.g. `Try`, `Future` or other IO), all results so far disappear. You would have to introduce a new monad, that would represent `A => (L, F[A2])`... but that is harder than it sounds. Personally I would go probably with something like `Ref` (from Cats Effect) or `TaskLocal` (from Monix) and wrote to it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how using Ref can one control the log accumulator when a method throws?

Comment: What about using WriteT with Either as an F. Making sure that your Either catches everything tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing functional logging (in a way that preserves logs even if error happened) using monad transformers like Writer (WriterT) or State (StateT) is hard. However, if we don't be anal about FP approach we could do the following:

- use some IO monad
- with it create something like in-memory storage for logs
- however implement in in a functional way

Personally I would pick either `cats.effect.concurrent.Ref` or `monix.eval.TaskLocal`.

Example using Ref (and Task):

```
type Log = Ref[Task, Chain[String]]
type FunctionalLogger = String => Task[Unit]
val createLog: Task[Log] = Ref.of[Task, Chain[String]](Chain.empty)
def createAppender(log: Log): FunctionalLogger =
  entry => log.update(chain => chain.append(entry))
def outputLog(log: Log): Task[Chain[String]] = log.get
```

with helpers like that I could:

```
def doOperations(logger: FunctionalLogger) = for {
  _ <- operation1(logger) // logging is a side effect managed by IO monad
  _ <- operation2(logger) // so it is referentially transparent
} yield result

createLog.flatMap { log =>
  doOperations(createAppender(log))
    .recoverWith(...)
    .flatMap { result =>
       outputLog(log)
       ...
    }
}
```

However, making sure that output is called is a bit of a pain so we could use some form of `Bracket` or `Resource` to handle it:

```
val loggerResource: Resource[Task, FunctionalLogger] = Resource.make {
  createLog // acquiring resource - IO operation that accesses something
} { log =>
  outputLog(log) // releasing resource - works like finally in try-catchso it should
    .flatMap(... /* log entries or sth */) // be called no matter if error occured
}.map(createAppender)

loggerResource.use { logger =>
  doSomething(logger)
}
```

If you don't like passing this appender around explicitly you could use Kleisli to inject it:

```
type WithLogger[A] = Kleisli[Task, FunctionalLogger, A]

// def operation1: WithLogger[A]
// def operation2: WithLogger[B]

def doSomething: WithLogger[C] = for {
  a <- operation1
  b <- operation2
} yield c

loggerResource.use { logger =>
  doSomething(logger)
}
```

`TaskLocal` would be used in a very similar way.

At the end of the day you would end up with:

- type that says that it is logging
- mutability managed through IO, so referential transparency would not be lost
- certainty that even if IO fails, log will be preserved and the results sent

I believe some purist would not like this solution, but it has all the benefits of FP, so I would personally use it.